# How do I Loop over json and post every index in camelcontext

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, javabeans

Let's say I have the following *CamelContext*:

```
<camelContext id="camelId"  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="upsertItem">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:someEndpoint" />
        <process ref="someTransformer" />
        <log message="$someJson"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

**$someJson** contains the following json:

```
{
   "0":{
      "title":"hello world",
      "description":"a greeting to the world"
   },
   "1":{
      "title":"goodbye world",
      "description":"a goodbye to the world"
   }
   //might have more indexes
}
```

I want to edit my *CamelContext* so it can post every index to an endpoint. The problem is that I can't find out how to iterate through the JSON.

So I want to have something that looks like this:

```
<loop src="${someJson[index]}">
    <to uri="http://bookstore/api/books"/>
</loop>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done by splitting the original message

```
<split>
    <jsonpath>$[*]</jsonpath>
    <log message="${body}"/>
</split>
```